# replacing "with" statement in Python code

Tags: python-2.7, pseudocode, with-statement

```
import json
with open("login_data.txt", "r") as login_file:
    try:
        users = json.load(login_file)
    except:
        users = {}
```

Recently, I'm doing a presentation for my code. However, my lecturer requires me to break down the code into pseudocode.

I can't find any pseudocode terms that fit in the `with` statement. I need to find alternative solution that can replace the `with` statement above.

```
 #i suppose it should look like this:...
def dummyname(login_file):
    login_file = process open("login_data.txt","r")
    while
        users != {}
    do
        users = process json.load(login_file)
process dummyname(login_file)
#is it something like this?
```

Comment: Top tip: bare `except:` is very bad practice.

Comment: @jonrsharpe `except ValueError:` should work right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind to write less safe pseudo-code ( and write safe after ) you could open-close.

```
login_file = open "login_data.txt" in text reading mode
users = load_json( login_file )
if load_json failed,
    users = {}
close( login_file )
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of replacing with statements, describe what is going on in pseudocode.  Context managers are fundamental programming elements.

Comment: i'll try my best to understand it~ Coz sometime i know how to use a code but without knowing how it works.